# Блокировка экрана телефона

Tags: java, android

Я хочу создать блокировку экрана android. В моём приложении также идёт время, после окончания которого я хотел бы реализовать блокировку экрана но пока без идей как это правильно делать (новичок). Сам же отсчёт времени у меня осуществляется с помощью метода CountDownTimer(){}.

Answer (score 2):

Если кратко, то это довольно сложно. Сложно не в смысле кодирования, а в смысле всяческих разрешений и проч. Нужно иметь права [администратора аппарата](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html), что может подтвердить только сам юзер, примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На практике, юзер особо не доверяет, конечно, всяким левым приложениям выдачу разрешений на администрирование аппарата.

Если это вас не останавливает, то посмотрите примеры [например здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44680730/472270) или [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352648/how-to-lock-unlock-screen-programmatically)

Писать здесь код не вижу смысла, поэтому изучайте.

Comment: Благодарю...буду изучать данные темы ибо завлекло это всё)